# Azure SB queues sends messages to disabled dead letter queue

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, dead-letter

Why does my Azure Service Bus queues send messages to the dead letter sub queue when it's not enabled?

Right from the beginning I made sure expired messages wouldn't be moved to the dead letter queue (or so I thought).

In Visual Studio Server Explorer I see this under my queues:

- EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration: False

But I also see this:

- DeadLetterMessageCount: 16

I can't pull them out as normal so I created a temporary service to handle (get rid of) these and this is what I was able to extract from the `brokeredMessage.Properties`:

- DeadLetterReason: MaxDeliveryCountExceeded
- DeadLetterErrorDescription: Message could not be consumed after 10 delivery attempts.

I would like the messages to just stay in the normal queue when they're not completed. So far I've changed MaxDeliveryCount to 1000 but it's not a real solution.

What am I overlooking?

**Update**
Upon reading my own text I realised EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration has nothing to do with delivery count.
Do I have any option to let my messages stay in the normal queue forever? Or do I have to set the MaxDeliveryCount "*high enough*"?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Messages will be moved to dead letter if they reached `MaxDeliveryCount`, even though you disable it. You may want to set `MaxDeliveryCount` to `0` or `int.MaxValue` to stop deadlettering.

NOTE: This information is not documented anywhere. I figured that out by finding people who work on ServiceBus Queue specifically.